# MethodInvocationTree usage in SonarQube using Java

Tags: java, sonarqube, customization

The requirement is to flag all the occurrences of `HttpSession session = request.getSession();`

I am using the Tree.Kind.METHOD_INVOCATION within the method nodesToVisit for intercepting all method invocations. I am successfully getting the instances of HttpSession

```
HttpSession session1 = request.getSession(); // Noncompliant
HttpSession session2 = request.getSession(true); // Noncompliant
```

But the symbol type for the tree comes to **!unknownSymbol!**

Appreciate any inputs here. Is any specific setting required for sonarqube analyzer to recognize ***javax.servlet*** package?

Comment: Since you're presumably writing a custom rule, you should [edit] the question to include the language you're dealing with.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam: I have updated the question with the details. Appreciate your inputs here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ***symbolType*** is unknown due to the missing libraries in the classpath. We need to add the dependency in the pom.xml for the custom plugin.

1. When testing the source code analysis via Junit, we must use the
   maven-dependency-plugin for providing the dependency jars.
2. After deploying the plugin in sonarqube, we need to add the
   following properties in sonar-project.properties.

sonar.java.libraries=lib/*.jar

sonar.java.test.libraries=lib/*.jar

Below is the plugin maven-dependency-plugin addition in the pom.xml.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>javax</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
                        <version>7.0</version>
                        <type>jar</type>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/test-jars</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```